# Citações em outro idioma, manter original ou somente tradução?

Tags: debate, tradução, proposta-para-faq

Em caso de citações vindas de outros conteúdos em outro idioma, na qual foi adicionada uma tradução ao português, qual a melhor opção?

- Manter as duas citações, já que a tradução pode ter uma interpretação errônea ou pessoal, porem deixando redundância na resposta.
- Deixar somente a versão traduzida com um link para o conteúdo original.

---

<sup>Exemplo: [Programar em C para ARM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/732/programar-em-c-para-arm). *É apenas um exemplo, deixo aqui a minha opinião de que a tradução foi fiel ao texto original e muito bem vinda.*</sup>

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169269/147423

Answer (score 6):

Particularmente prefiro a primeira, afinal é uma citação e deve mostrar o conteúdo original. A tradução é extremamente útil e deve ser, no mínimo, incentivada, mas é adicional à citação. A redundância não é problema. E a informação aqui no site é sempre melhor que apenas um link, mesmo que em outra língua.

Vale ressaltar que não precisa trazer qualquer conteúdo em língua estrangeira para o site. Isso vale basicamente onde é feita a citação direta, como proposta na pergunta.

O exemplo demonstrado está perfeito e todas suas obervações sobre o procedimento da tradução de citação está adequado ao site.